# How configure VirtualBox shortcuts to switch between virtual computer and host with single key combination on windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, virtualbox, windows-10

In practice it's always possible with first pressing `host` button while virtual computer has keyboard focus and then pressing usual windows 10 shortcut `ctrl + windows + left/right`.

Is it anyhow configurable on Virtualbox to add a shortcut that captures a key combination and switch between windows workspaces, while Im using the virtual computer on full screen mode. Vitualbox itself captures many of the keystores like `host+F`, `host+L`, `host+E`, etc. Can I somehow add a shortcut similiar to these to switch back to windows and go to another workspace with a **single** key combination like `host + alt + left/right`

---

*Update:* Apparently depending on the touch-pad model, as long as it supports multi-finger gestures like 3-4 finger swipes, the touch-pad can be used to switch between VM and host no matter who has the keyboard and mouse focus. So this can be a OEM dependent feature. (Tested with Microsoft Surface)

Comment: Related [Getting host to capture certain key presses in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/q/108785/664)

Comment: Related [request: keybinding passthrough](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=34586), [Sending key combinations to the host when the guest has captured the keyboard](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=84753)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Does one of these works for you:

- `Host key` + `m`, minimize virtualbox os window,
- Click `Host key` once and release to let the vm lose focus, then `Alt` + `Tab`, switch to a window of residing os,

**Tips:**

- The `Host key` is used to transfer focus to residing os, on windows or linux it's `right Ctrl` by default.
- If the vm already lose focus, then you don't need to press the `Host key` first, otherwise you need to press once & release, to transfer focus back to residing os.
- If you switch back to the vm again via `Alt` + `Tab`, then vm will get focus again, then to get back to residing os, you need to press `Host key` again.

---

### **The virtualbox `Auto Capture Keyboard` option**

*(from `File -> Preference -> Input`)*.

**Behavior:**

- If checked, then you need `Host key` to return focus to residing os, just as described above.
- If unchecked, then vm is just treated as a simple window in host. You can use `Alt` + `Tab` to switch to a window from host anytime, without press the `Host key` first. But, you also can't switch within windows inside the vm, via `Alt` + `Tab` any more.

**Which to use:**

There is a trade off, it depends on what you use the vm for to decide whether check it or not.
In my case:

- When I am using Windows vm on a Linux host.
  In the Windows vm browser with proxy is the only thing I need most of the time, and most of the time I am on Linux host.
  So I uncheck it, so that never need to click `Host key` to get back to Linux host.
- When I am using Linux vm on a Windows host.
  Actually most of the time I am working on the linux vm, and sometimes need to go to the Windows host.
  So I check it, so that I can switch between windows of Linux vm via `Alt` + `Tab`, and when I need to go back to Windows host, I click `Host key` first or use mouse.

Comment: Right_Ctrl + m on Win7. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: How is `Host key` + `Ctrl` + `Tab` supposed to work? Could you please provide any reference?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I corrected the answer a bit, basically you press the `Host key` once, to let the vm lose focus, then you can use `Alt` + `Tab` to switch to a window of residing OS.

Comment: Neither the first nor the second option answers the question which asks for _**single** key combination_.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. What you need is some way to trigger VirtualBox actions from within VirtualBox (e.g. `VBoxClient minimize`), but that doesn't exist as far as I can tell.

There are a few super janky ways to accomplish this:

- Share a folder `shared` between host & guest. On the guest, `switch-workspace && touch shared/foo`. On the host, whenever `shared/foo` is modified, minimize VirtualBox.
- Get port forwarding between guest and host, communicate that you want VirtualBox to be minimized.

Those are both pretty high-effort projects just to save an extra keypress, though.

Comment: +1 for explanation and the idea... +1000 will come, once you implement this and share a step by step instruction on how this shared folder solutions works :)

Answer (score 0):

Host + L to switch desktop integrated mode. Then you can switch from taskbar.